# ローカル開発環境におけるPHPでのfacebookのログイン認証について

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

質問させていただきます

現在ローカル環境（netbeans,phpmyadmin）でのPHPでfacebookにログインできるように取り組んでいるのですが、`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found`となり、そこから先に進めず困っています。

ドットインストールさんのサイトを見ながら作成しているのですが、リダイレクトURIに制限モードを使用がいいえに変更してくださいと記載されていますが、変更出来ません。それが原因なのでしょうか？？

それとも他に原因があるのか、教えていただきたいです。よろしくおねがいします。
ちなみにcomposerで進めてきました。

Comment: 念の為どのページを参考に作成されてるのか質問文に追記されたほうが良いかと思います。(自身が投稿した質問文は自由に編集できます)
https://dotinstall.com/search?q=Facebook&f=topbar

Comment: あと`Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found`というエラーなので、最低限そのエラーが発生したソースコードは質問文に追記したほうが解決する可能性が高まります。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。

Comment: 参考にさせて頂き、また改めて質問させていただこうと思います